# I am Trying to add NSMutableDictionary To NSMutableArray with objectAtIndex and save in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting this error on my project in Xcode;

NSRangeException [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

```
     monthValueArray= [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] mutableCopy];
        if (quaterType == 1)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *jan = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] mutableCopy];
            jan=[monthValueArray objectAtIndex:0];
            [jan setObject:slidertext.text forKey:@"monthPercentage"];
            [self.monthValueArray addObject:jan];
        }
     if (quaterType == 1)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *feb = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] mutableCopy];
            feb=[monthValueArray objectAtIndex:1];
            [feb setObject:slidertext1.text forKey:@"monthPercentage1"];
            [monthValueArray addObject:feb];
        }
        if (quaterType == 1)
            {
         NSMutableDictionary *mar = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] mutableCopy];
                mar=[monthValueArray objectAtIndex:2];
                [mar setObject:totJantext2.text forKey:@"totalOfTheMonth2"];
                [monthValueArray addObject:mar];
            }
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:monthValueArray]]forKey:@"MonthValues"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

As Like QuarterType i have 4 Quarter and i am doing addObject of NSMUtableDictionary to monthValueArray. 
I Want add dictionary to userdefaults to store the Value and show it.

```
QuarterType==1 [objectAtIndex:0][objectAtIndex:1][objectAtIndex:2]
QuarterType==2 [objectAtIndex:3][objectAtIndex:4][objectAtIndex:5]
QuarterType==3 [objectAtIndex:6][objectAtIndex:7][objectAtIndex:8]
QuarterType==4 [objectAtIndex:9][objectAtIndex:10][objectAtIndex:11]
```

when i am run the app this log Are Come:-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: You just allocated `monthValueArray`. It don't have any values in it, then how can you access the non-existing values using objectAtIndex: ?

Comment: Interesting culprit code line      monthValueArray= [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] mutableCopy]; :( :(

Answer (score 0):

The error most probably arises in one of these lines:

```
jan=[monthValueArray objectAtIndex:0];
feb=[monthValueArray objectAtIndex:1];
mar=[monthValueArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

The problem is that your *monthValueArray* is empty and you are trying to retrieve an object from an empty array. If you want to do so, you should first populate this array.

So right now you array is just `[]`. If you try `objectAtIndex:` method, it will try to retrieve an object from the specified index that does not exist in an empty array

You can also **clearly** see what you are doing wrong from the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for **empty array**'

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that your monthValueArray is empty array. You are trying to get data from EMPTY array.

Comment: Ya want add the value in empty Array and stored it

Answer (score 0):

1) you don't have to do `[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] mutableCopy]`, the instance you get from the first 2 methods call (alloc &init) give you a mutable instance of NSDictionary.

2) you are calling `jan=[monthValueArray objectAtIndex:0];` 2 lines ofter you are creating the array `monthValueArray= [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] mutableCopy];`,

**EDIT**

I think you are confusing two methods

- `[monthValueArray objectAtIndex: <indexNumber>]` - get you a reference to the object in the  in the array object

you need to call `[monthValueArray addObject: <your object>]` or `[array insertObjectAtIndex: <indexNumber>]`

From your code you can see that you first get a reference to your object by calling the `[monthValueArray objectAtIndex: <indexNumber>]` but the array is empty at that time. You need to call `[monthValueArray addObject: <yourObject>]` first in order to have any objects in the `monthValueArray`

Comment: just one time i am create monthValueArray and and adding nsmutabledictionary to it at objectatindex

Comment: i have edited my answer,  i believe you are confusing two different methods.

Comment: thanks , i just want to add the data in indexs of array to access it in other view

Comment: Cool, if my answer helped you please check it as the answer so other can understand.

Comment: Thanks :- This is work after addobject calling [monthValueArray ObjectatIndex:0]; Perfectly fine